# Tutorials/References/HowTos to learn Glade GTK+ with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reference, gtk, glade

I am trying to design some simple GUIs with Glade to use with Ruby. I am not having so much luck finding tutorials/references on how to actually interface glade with Ruby however. I have found maybe 1 or 2 hello world tutorials that show how to use a button to change a title of a window but is there a reference that tells me what each of the signals/handlers do and how to use functionality such as comboboxes, listboxes, tree structures etc..?

If you guys had any information to give me to help learn Glade with Ruby I would be most thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [RSQLiteGUI](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rsqlitegui/). It's a small Glade app, so you get an overview really quick. Still it's bigger than HelloWorld and it should show you most concepts.

Comment: I guess this is what will have to do if there are no good tutorials out there. Thanks!